# Regex optional group

Tags: regex, option-type, regex-group

I am using this regex:

```
((?:[a-z][a-z]+))_(\d+)_((?:[a-z][a-z]+)\d+)_(\d{13})
```

to match strings like this:

```
SH_6208069141055_BC000388_20110412101855
```

separating into 4 groups:

```
SH
6208069141055
BC000388
20110412101855
```

**Question:** How do I make the first group optional, so that the resulting group is a empty string?
I want to get 4 groups in every case, when possible.

Input string for this case: (no underline after the first group)

```
6208069141055_BC000388_20110412101855
```

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can easily simplify your regex to be this:

```
(?:([a-z]{2,})_)?(\d+)_([a-z]{2,}\d+)_(\d+)$
^              ^^
|--------------||
| first group  ||- quantifier for 0 or 1 time (essentially making it optional)
```

I'm not sure whether the input string without the first group will have the underscore or not, but you can use the above regex if it's the whole string.

[regex101 demo](http://www.regex101.com/r/wG3aM3)

As you can see, the matched group 1 in the second match is empty and starts at matched group 2.

Comment: Which of the characters is marking the group optional?

Comment: The `?` after the first group? That's the 17th character from the left.

Answer (score 232):

Making a non-capturing, zero to more matching group, you must append `?`.

```
(?: ..... )?
^          ^____ optional
|____ group
```

Comment: what is the difference between option group and (...)*

Comment: @GoldenLion `?` matches "zero or one times" and `*` matches "zero or many times"

Comment: What does the ```?:``` at the start of the group do?

Comment: @brobers a normal group `(...)` will capture the content in the results, but `(?:...)` makes it a non-capturing group, so it must match (or apply) but will not be included in the resulting groups.