# regex optional floating decimal

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have a MySQL double(10,2) which I've applied the following regex: `/^\d{0,10}\.\d{2}$/`

I'm not passing validation for `1234`, I'm assuming the decimal is required (I understood `?` is the optional char which is absent).

Where do I place the `?` char in this regex?

thanks

Comment: Why are you treating them as text?  Whats the ultimate aim here?

Comment: @AlexK. to place a number from 0 to 9999999999.99 without requiring a decimal, you can skip the "only numeric" part since I am using a validation package and I just add "numeric|regex: /.../"

Comment: `/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{2})?$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - thanks, set as answer. short and sweet.

Comment: `/^\d{1,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`, otherwise you will not accept `123.4`, and also it is good to have at least one digit before the dot.

Comment: Yeah, it depends on what the actual requirements are. If 1 digit after `.` is expected, the `{2}` should be replaced with `{1,2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve the immediate problem you need an [optional group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633334/regex-optional-group) around `\.\d{2}` pattern - `(\.\d{2})?`:

```
/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{2})?$/
```

It matches 0 to 10 digits from the start of the string and then either requires the end of the string, or `.` and 2 digits.

Next step, you may allow 1 or 2 digits in the fractional part using a `{1,2}` [limiting quantifier](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html#limit):

```
/^\d{0,10}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

And even use a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do) to get some very tiny efficiency boost:

```
/^\d{0,10}(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```