# How can I add the "X" or "Y" value from a line above without reading lines not containing "X" and "Y" to the line that is missing the value?

Tags: python

So i a .csv that has a simplified machine programm that looks like this:

```
X51.972,Y1433.401
LASER_ON
X41.972
Y1438.401
X51.97
LASER_OFF
X51.972,Y1382.401
LASER_ON
X41.972
Y1377.401
X51.97
```

When there is only an X value, I want to write the Y value from the line above next to the X value and when there is only a Y value i want it to write the X value next to it.

```
lines: list[tuple[str, str]] = []

with open(output_csv_file) as input_file:
    for line in map(str.strip, input_file):
        if line:
            a, *b = line.split(",")
            if a[0] == "X":
                if b:
                    lines.append((a, b[0]))
                else:
                    lines.append((a, lines[-1][1]))
            else:
                assert a[0] == "Y"
                if b:
                    lines.append((b[0], a))
                else:
                    lines.append((lines[-1][0], a))

with open(output_csv_file, 'w', newline ='') as output_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    for line in lines:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

I managed to do what i want with this script but this only works, when there are no lines, that contain "LASER_ON" and LASER_OFF". Can i modify this to skip the lines containing these words?

Comment: Of course you can.  I don't think you thought about the problem.  `if line.startswith('LASER'):` / `continue`.

Comment: Just adding 'if line.startswith('LASER'): / continue' didnt fix my problem.

Comment: What problem?  You said what you wanted.  You didn't say there was a problem.

Comment: Sorry im pretty new to programming. It doesnt wirte the "LASER_ON" and "LASER_OFF" lines to the output .csv. Do i have to change something in the writerow statement?

Comment: You didn't say that in your question.  You just said you want to skip them.  Yes, that takes more work.  I'll try to fix it.

Comment: Im sorry for that thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is that you have to track the last values of X and Y.  If there's a LASER line, you leave those two values alone but save the record.  Also, you can't really use the CSV module to write the data if the lines are variable in length.

```
output_csv_file = 'x.csv'

lines = []
X = 'X0'
Y = 'Y0'
with open(output_csv_file) as input_file:
    for line in map(str.strip, input_file):
        if not line:
            continue
        if line.startswith('LASER'):
            lines.append([line])
        else:
            row = line.split(",")
            if len(row) == 2:
                X,Y = row
            elif row[0][0] == 'X':
                X = row[0]
            else:
                Y = row[0]
            lines.append((X,Y))

with open(output_csv_file, 'w') as output_file:
    for line in lines:
        print( ','.join(line), file=output_file )
```

Output:

```
X51.972,Y1433.401
LASER_ON
X41.972,Y1433.401
X41.972,Y1438.401
X51.97,Y1438.401
LASER_OFF
X51.972,Y1382.401
LASER_ON
X41.972,Y1382.401
X41.972,Y1377.401
X51.97,Y1377.401
```

Comment: the csv module can handle variable length entries, just provide tuples with different lengths

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use [regular expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html) to check for [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18633334/regex-optional-group) X and Y entries.

To keep the Laser entries, I included an `last_valid` as a tracker for the last valid entry, from which missing values are looked up.

```py
import csv
import re

data = """X51.972,Y1433.401
LASER_ON
X41.972
Y1438.401
X51.97
LASER_OFF
X51.972,Y1382.401
LASER_ON
X41.972
Y1377.401
X51.97"""

lines = []
re_float = "[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*"
last_valid = "", ""
for line in map(str.strip, data.splitlines()):
    # look for optional X and Y entries
    result = re.match(rf"(X{re_float})?,?(Y{re_float})?$", line)
    if not result:
        # no X or Y entry found, store line and start next loop
        lines.append((line,))
        continue
    # X or Y found, replace missing entries
    x, y = result.groups()
    if x is None:
        x = last_valid[0]
    elif y is None:
        y = last_valid[1]
    # append entries and update last_valid
    last_valid = x,y
    lines.append(last_valid)

with open("temp.csv", "w", newline="") as output_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(output_file)

    for line in lines:
        csv_writer.writerow(line)
```